# Add attributes to multiple <td> in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have code that adds attributes to the `<td>` tags when the table is drawn. Currently this code only works on the 3rd `<td>`. What is the proper way to adapt this code to work with multiple targets? Code below.

```
<script>
$(function(){
     $('#customers').DataTable({
       data: data,
       'createdRow': function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
            $(row).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
          $(row).attr('data-id', + dataIndex);
          $(row).attr('data-target', '#infoModal');
        },
      'columnDefs': [
     {
        'targets': 3,
        'createdCell':  function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
           $(td).attr('style', 'display: none;');
        }
     }
  ]
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: There is a simpler built in option to hide columns without needing to use jQuery on each cell. Forget exactly what it is but should be easy to find in docs

Comment: I tried to use the method recommended in the docs but it actually removes the <td> from the document and I needed to manipulate its value while it isn’t being displayed. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: You still have access to values of all data though even when the cell isn't rendered. For example can use a non rendered column for sorting/searching. Can also update a non rendered element in data when something else changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting column 3 with this setting:

```
'targets': 3
```

You can modify that for multiple targets by using the following format:

```
'targets': [3,6,9]
```

If you want it to apply to ALL cells, then omit the target setting.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the quick answer!